# UITableView objective-c not populating correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying display cells in a `UITableView` but newly added cells are not displayed unless `viewDidLoad` is used.

[image: Full list]

This is the full list:
If I go to the `New Note` screen and come back this is fine but if this screen is accessed by the side menu the note title `New` disappears until I click on the `New Note` button and come back.

Below is the code for this page:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *leftButtonsArray = [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems mutableCopy];
    UIBarButtonItem *newNoteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Note" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addNote:)];
    [leftButtonsArray addObject:newNoteButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftButtonsArray;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.notes = [NSMutableArray array];

    ontracAppDelegate *delegate = (ontracAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Notes"];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated" ascending:NO];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sd];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSNumber * NOTEID = @"noteID";
    NSString * PACKID = @"pack_id";
    NSString * NOTE   = @"note";
    NSString * CREATED  = @"created";
    NSString * UPDATED = @"updated";

    NSDictionary * dict;

    [self.notes removeAllObjects];

    for(Notes *note in results){

        if(self.dataObject.pack_id == [note.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id integerValue]){
            dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                note.noteID, NOTEID,
                note.pack_id, PACKID,
                note.note, NOTE,
                note.created, CREATED,
                note.updated, UPDATED,
                nil];

            if((note.created == nil || note.updated == nil || note.noteID == nil)){
                [moc deleteObject:note];
            }else{
                [self.notes addObject:dict];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"mArray %@", self.notes);

 }
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:          (NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"notes count: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.notes count]);
    return [self.notes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *d = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSNumber *noteID = [d valueForKey:@"noteID"];
    NSString *note = [d valueForKey:@"note"];
    NSString *created = [d valueForKey:@"created"];
    NSString *updated = [d valueForKey:@"updated"];

    cell.textLabel.text = note;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date Created: %@ | Last Updated %@", created, updated];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSNumber *noteID = [d valueForKey:@"noteID"];
    NID = noteID;

    ontracSuperClassViewController *viewController = [[ontracNotesViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)addNote:(id)sender{
    NID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1];
    ontracSuperClassViewController *viewController = [[ontracNotesViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: After `NSLog(@"mArray %@", self.notes);`, do `[yourTableView reloadData];`, or use a `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: as you say you have add a new notes in new viewcontroller then use nsnotificationcenter addobserver and call that method from new viewcontroller and update your array with new value and reload table

Comment: When U pushed to second view controller, what do you use to get back here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill your array with latest updated data then you have to reload `tableview` to display that latest data. So, if your `self.notes` prints updated data properly in `viewWillAppear` in `NSLog` then you just need to `reload` your `tableview` like,

```
   [tableView reloadData];
```

and if you are not getting updated data in `self.notes` then first solve that and then reload `tableview`!

Answer (score 2):

whenever you add new note in that function after adding new node just reload the tableview

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your `viewDidLoad()` method

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.Methodtablereloadata(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)


-(void) Methodtablereloadata(notification: NSNotification){
        //Take Action on Notification
         self.notes = [NSMutableArray array];

ontracAppDelegate *delegate = (ontracAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [delegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Notes"];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSError *error = nil;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sd];
NSArray *sortedArray = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSNumber * NOTEID = @"noteID";
NSString * PACKID = @"pack_id";
NSString * NOTE   = @"note";
NSString * CREATED  = @"created";
NSString * UPDATED = @"updated";

NSDictionary * dict;

[self.notes removeAllObjects];

for(Notes *note in results){

    if(self.dataObject.pack_id == [note.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id integerValue]){
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            note.noteID, NOTEID,
            note.pack_id, PACKID,
            note.note, NOTE,
            note.created, CREATED,
            note.updated, UPDATED,
            nil];

        if((note.created == nil || note.updated == nil || note.noteID == nil)){
            [moc deleteObject:note];
        }else{
            [self.notes addObject:dict];
        }
    }
  }
  [YOURTABLE reloadData];
 }
```

**your next viewcontoller that you add new notes . after add notes just write one line for reload table**

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Refer this link

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter